# Is there an ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter function for Non-Angular pages

Tags: angularjs, filter, protractor

Please let me know if there exists an ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter function for elements on Non-Angular pages. 
If not, is there any alternative method available for filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can already use `ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter` on non-angular pages as long as you first set:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Before navigating into the page and start testing.

Full example:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.get('/your-non-angular-page');
browser.sleep(2000); // when ignoring sync, Protractor won't wait so it becomes your job. see browser.wait()

$$('.items li').filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text === 'Third';
  });
}).then(function(filteredElements) {
  filteredElements[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. I tried this on table rows which gave me 'Object has no method filter' error.

Comment: Ensure you have latest Protractor >= 1.2 and you are using double dollar `$$` not single dollar `$`.